# Linking an object file to the C standard library with ld

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

Say I'm trying to create an executable binary from:

```c
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

I can just run `gcc main.c` and I get the executable binary `a.out` that prints `Hello, world!", as desired.

I've been told that `gcc` did two things here:\

1. Compiled `main.c` to a object code, and
2. Linked that code with the stardard library so that `printf` works.\

How can I manually accomplish these two steps manually, one-by-one?

I start compiling `main.c` to object code by running `gcc -c main.c`, creating the object file `main.o`. Now I'd like to do the linking step. It seems I can do this, also with `gcc`, by simply running `gcc main.o`, producing the executable binary `a.out`.

I've read that this second invocation of `gcc` is actually running the linker `ld` under the hood. How can I do this with `ld` directly, instead of with a second invocation of `gcc`? If I run `ld main.o`, I get a warning and an error:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0
ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `printf'
```

The error seems to suggest that I need to tell it to link to the C standard library so I can use `printf`. I can with the `-lc` flag `ld main.o -lc`. This produces `a.out`, but I still get the warning:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004002e0
```

And when I run `a.out`, it prints `Hello, world!` all over the screen, forever:

```
Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello,
```

**What's the correct way to invoke `ld` here to eliminate the warning and get the correct executable?**

Comment: I suggest using gcc -v to see how gcc works under the hood. As far as I know it is platform dependent how ld is invoked.

Comment: Also I assume you are doing this just to learn about gcc and ld? It is not advisable to call ld directly. gcc is a much better frontend for ld.

Comment: Yes. This I understand that this is not something to do in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the correct way to invoke ld here to eliminate the warning and get the correct executable?

The *only* correct way to link a user-space C binary is by using the appropriate compiler front end: `gcc main.o`.

Using `ld` directly is *never* correct.

You can see what `gcc` actually does by invoking `gcc -v main.o`. Note however that the resulting `ld` (or `collect2` command):

- may differ depending on how your `gcc` was configured
- may differ between different OS releases
- may differ depending on which `libc` is being used

TL;DR: you are welcome to learn how `gcc` invokes `ld` on your system, but you should not put the result into any `Makefile` or a build script.